# Avoid repeating ExtendWith extensions for each test method in each class

Tags: java, junit5

Each test is extended with same extensions

```
@ExtendWith({FishTaggingExtension.class, AllureAttachmentsExtension.class, BStackContextExtension.class})
```

Is there a way to avoid repeating this line for every test method?
Can I somehow configure this in some base class and automatically apply to every test in a class that extends such base class?

Alternatively - can I write a check that would throw error if some test is not extended like this?

I'm using gradle, junit5.

edit:

Thanks to @JoachimSauer comment, I did a Meta-Annotation, and it does what I wanted.

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@ExtendWith({FishTaggingExtension.class, AllureAttachmentsExtension.class, BStackContextExtension.class})
@ArgumentsSource(TestDataJsonRead.class)
public @interface ProjectTest {
}
```

Comment: You can use reflection to check if the methods of the class have the annotation, if not, abort the test

Comment: You can collapse that whole list into a simple-to-use [Meta-Annotation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-meta-annotations) so each test would only need a single `@MyCustomTest` annotation. And since `@ExtendsWith` [is inherited](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-registration-inheritance) you only need it on a shared base class. You can use either approach or combine them.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I think the Meta-Annotation will solve this for me. Thank you for this suggestion.